# SQL: COUNT DISTINCT over more groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
        date_trunc('week', q.order_date::date+2)::date-2 AS weekly,
        COUNT(DISTINCT q.provider_username) AS engaged_providers
FROM tbl_quotes q
GROUP BY weekly
```

What I need is to COUNT(DISTINCT q.provider_username) over 4 weeks, not just one, and I don't want to change my date-trunc. obviously I can't use OVER(ORDER BY ...) because DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output(Text format only, no images). Don't expect us to guess by looking at your  query to know what you want the query to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data and desired results would really help.  For one interpretation of your question, I would suggest a correlated subquery.  The date arithmetic is a bit arcane, but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT weekly,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT q.provider_username)
        FROM tbl_quotes q
        WHERE q.order_date >= w.weekly - interval '3 week' and
              q.order_date < w.weekly + interval '1 week'
       ) as engaged_providers
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('week', q.order_date::date+2)::date-2 as weekly
      FROM tbl_quotes q
     ) w;
```